# Windows 8 GridView Drag/touch issue

Tags: gridview, windows-8, drag-and-drop, touch, windows-store-apps

the touch experience inside the Gridview while dragging in my windows8 App is not correct as when I try to dragitem from Gridview in both right/left directions it's considered as panning & according to below user experience document :dragging is allowed only in up/down direction is there anyway to override this behavior ?

[image]

I've also disabled scrolling but still can't drag in right/left directions (happens only in touch mode & it's working fine in mouse mode ),Do you know how solve this issue ?

Additionally is it allowed to modify above distance thresholds ?

-Video for this issue **touch** drag Right/Left  (the issue):
http://youtu.be/ybEH4bmnWpU

Comment: i've uploaded this issue in the following Link http://youtu.be/ybEH4bmnWpU

Comment: -While Mouse-Drag RightLeft Direction working fine with **mouse** : http://youtu.be/ufXMIkkAuCA